# How to install java 17 on Mac using brew and setting up java_home?

Tags: macos, installation, java-17, java-home

Install java 17 on Mac using brew and setting up java_home

I tried this:

```
brew install java17  

> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
  100\.0%
> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
  100\.0%
> Warning: No available formula with the name "java17". Did you mean javacc?
> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
> Error: Cask java6 exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/java6
> caskroom/versions/java6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming brew is already installed and updated:

```
brew install openjdk@17
```

If using bash:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or using zsh (on macOS Catalina or newer), then it should be:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Restart your shell.

If you have multiple JDK versions installed, you can specify one, using `-v` flag:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Check the java version:

```
java --version

openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: that did not work for me

Comment: @Davinanaya What exactly didn't work? You should mention an error message or whatnot.

@Pri  After installing `openjdk@17` from brew, brew prints this info `For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk`
If this is not done, `java_home -v 17` won't return the newly installed JDK path.